# Different formatting of HAML to HTML on rails production server compared to development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a production and development rails servers, I am using HAML, and when I view page source on the production server the generated html looks unformatted like this:

```
<div class='span4'>
<div class='info-bullet'>
<i class='icon-tags'></i>
<h5>Responsive Template</h5>
<p>Vestibulum placerat purus sed nunc tincidunt ultrices et. Vivamus pharetra aliquet nisi non pretium.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

However when I view the same page source on my local server the code is properly formatted and looks like this:

```
<div class='span4'>
  <div class='info-bullet'>
    <i class='icon-tags'></i>
    <h5>Responsive Template</h5>
    <p>Vestibulum placerat purus sed nunc tincidunt ultrices et. Vivamus pharetra aliquet nisi non pretium.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any setting to turn formatting on?

site url: http://soziev.com/theme_venera/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour take a look at the FAQ:

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-indentation-in-production

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know if there is a way to change it?